# How to get my Python script to go to a URL, download the latest file

Tags: python, url, xls, xlrd, xlwt

I have written this Python script to create a sheet with only the athletes from our sports club from the national rankings.  At the moment I have to download the rankings file and then re-name it.

```
#import the writer
import xlwt
#import the reader
import xlrd
#open the rankings spreadsheet
book = xlrd.open_workbook('rankings.xls')
#open the first sheet
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
#print the values in the second column of the first sheet
print first_sheet.col_values(1)


#open the spreadsheet
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
#add a sheet named "Club BFA ranking"
worksheet1 = workbook.add_sheet("Club BFA ranking")
#in cell 0,0 (first cell of the first row) write "Ranking"
worksheet1.write(0, 0, "Ranking")
#in cell 0,1 (second cell of the first row) write "Name"
worksheet1.write(0, 1, "Name")    
#save and create the spreadsheet file
workbook.save("saxons.xls")

name = []
rank = []
for i in range(first_sheet.nrows):
    #print(first_sheet.cell_value(i,3)) 
    if('Saxon' in first_sheet.cell_value(i,3)):  
        name.append(first_sheet.cell_value(i,1))
        rank.append(first_sheet.cell_value(i,8))    
        print('a')
for j in range(len(name)):
    worksheet1.write(j+1,0,rank[j])
    worksheet1.write(j+1,1,name[j])


workbook.save("saxons.xls")
```

As a next iteration I would like it to go to a specific URL and download the latest spreadsheet to use as rankings.xls

How can I do that?

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests) library. For example,

```
import requests

url = "YOUR_URL" 
downloaded_file = requests.get(url)

with open("YOUR_PATH/rankings.xls", 'wb') as file:  
    file.write(downloaded_file.content)
```

**EDIT:** You mentioned that you wanted to download the latest version of the file, you can use [time](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#module-time) as below to fill in the month & year.

```
time.strftime("https://www.britishfencing.com/wp-content/uploads/%Y/%m/ranking_file.xls")
```

as `YOUR_URL`to get the latest month's rankings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what you mean with "latest" spreadsheet, but you have various options to download files from the net. I'd suggest to use the famous requests library which is very, very easy to use.

Do a

```
pip install requests
```

before doing a

```
import requests
url = "http://foobar.com/rankings.xls"
r = requests.get(url)
```

then push the contents into a file

```
with open('./rankings.xls', 'w') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

So it would be possible to check if your recently downloaded rankings.xls is newer than a previously downloaded rankins.xls by comparing them using a hashcode or so.

EDIT: OP asked for a method to extract the latest xls file from the page. I'd suggest to parse the html for hrefs containing xls (as the page OP wants to parse is providing no common format for the xls files to be downloaded).

Best way to do this would be BeautifulSoup:

```
 pip install bs4

 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests

 x=requests.get('https://www.britishfencing.com/results-rankings/mens-foil-ranking-archive/')
 soup = BeautifulSoup(x.content, 'html.parser')
 result = [ xls['href'] for xls in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if 'xls' in xls['href']]

 print(result[0])
```

Comment: apologies I should have mentioned that the page I want to download from is an archive that has a file added once a month: https://www.britishfencing.com/results-rankings/mens-foil-ranking-archive/ is it possible to download the last uploaded file?

Comment: I'd go for beautifulsoup to get all links, then parse them for xls files and by order of their entrance, the first one will be the most recent.

Comment: how would I do that? I like the sound of it